# bootstrap button toolbar style is not applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

I created a 'AddCustomElement' class to create button toolbar, button group and button like this :

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'font-gis/css/font-gis.css'
import 'iconicss/dist/iconicss.css'
import 'bootstrap';


class AddCustomElement {

    static CreateToolbar({nb_groups}) {
        this.Toolbar = document.createElement("div")
        this.Toolbar.className="btn-toolbar"
        this.Toolbar.role = "toolbar"
        for (let i=0; i < nb_groups; i++) {
            this.AddButtonGroup(this.Toolbar, i)
        }
        return this.Toolbar
    }

    static AddButtonGroup(target, id) {
        let el= document.createElement('div');
        el.className = "btn-group me-2";
        el.role = "group";
        el.id = `group-${id}`;
        target.appendChild(el);
        return el;
    };

    static AddCustomButton({id, target, title, icon, isActive}) {
        let el = document.createElement('button');
        el.className = 'btn btn-primary';
        el.id = id;
        el.title = title;
        el.innerHTML = `<i class="${icon}"</i>`;
        el.disabled = !isActive;
        target.appendChild(el);
        return el;
    };
}

export default AddCustomElement;
```

I  use this class inside EditBar class to add button to my sidebar like this

```
import AddCustomElement from '../miscellaneous/AddCustomElement';

/**
 * @module widget/EditBar
 */

class EditBar {
  constructor(target) {
    // Creation de la toolbar générale
    this.Toolbar = AddCustomElement.CreateToolbar({
      nb_groups: 3
    })

    // Bouton de sélection
    this.SelectButton = AddCustomElement.AddCustomButton({
      id: 'S1',
      target: this.Toolbar.childNodes[0], 
      title: 'Select', 
      icon: 'fg-arrow-o', 
      isActive : true
    })
    
    target.addWidgetElement(this.Toolbar)
  };
}

export default EditBar;
```

This work well but i have a problem with bootstrap as the default bootstrap style is not applied and i have no idea why. I tried to import bootstrap in first position but it didn't work. Any idea on how to correct it ?

Here is a codeSandbox of my code : https://codesandbox.io/p/github/vprint/ol-js-dom/main?

Comment: If you use your browser developer tools to inspect a `button.btn`, you'll see that most of the Bootstrap styling from Bootstrap's `.btn` and `.btn-primary` rules are being overridden by OpenLayers's `.ol-control button` rule, since the later has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the former.

Comment: I modify 'style.css' like this : `@import "node_modules/ol/ol.css";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`
 but i still have the problem

Comment: Yes, it is because that most of the Bootstrap styling from Bootstrap's `.btn` and `.btn-primary` rules are being overridden by OpenLayers's `.ol-control button` rule, since the later has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the former. Ordering of the `@import`s will not have any effect on this.